# How to remove commits from a pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I did a pull request but after that I made some commits to the project locally which ended polluting my pull request, I tried to remove it but without any luck.

I found some similar questions on StackOverflow but I can't apply what's in there.
It's my first pull request on GitHub so it's kinda strange to me how all of this works.

The highlighted commit is the one I need to keep and remove all the other stuff.
It becomes the fourth commit in the history because I make some merge stuff.

[image]

my git log
[image]

Can someone please explain what's going on and how to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), and only "pick" the "added from github" commit (i.e. comment out the lines for every other commit)

Comment: rebase what branch onto what branch can you please add more explanation.

Comment: `what branch` = the branch you're working on, `onto what branch` = the branch you're pull requesting into

Comment: I explained what @Robbie Averill hinted in my answer. It's strange that nobody wrote an answer explaining this until now.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951901/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-modified-file-from-a-github-pull-request-via-the-gith

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You have several techniques to do it.

[This post - read the part about the revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716) will explain in details what we want to do and how to do it.

Here is the most simple solution to your problem:

```
# Checkout the desired branch
git checkout <branch>

# Undo the desired commit
git revert <commit>

# Update the remote with the undo of the code
# The force is a tricky flag since it will force the push but
# your administrator can block it, so if it's not an option you
# can delete the old branch and push it again
git push origin <branch> --force
```

The revert command will create a new commit with the **undo** of the original commit.

Comment: Does it work even when we forked the project from some another person and wanna remove some comments in pull request?

Comment: to revert all commit from pull request you only need Merge pull request commit id.
# Undo the desired commits from pull request

`git revert <Merge pull request commit id> -m 1`

Comment: You are right @Deeppak, just clarifying that the -m stands for the parent of the merge so you might need to use `-m n` instead of 1

Comment: @Dr.jacky if you're working on a forked project, just use `git push --force` after the `git revert <commit>` command. This will revert the commit on the PR.

Comment: `push --force` might be disabled by the git admin

Answer (score 336):

People wouldn't like to see a wrong commit and a revert commit to undo  changes of the wrong commit. This pollutes commit history.

Here is a simple way for removing the wrong commit instead of undoing changes with a revert commit.

0. `git checkout my-pull-request-branch`
1. `git rebase -i HEAD~n` // where `n` is the number of last commits you want to include in interactive
   rebase.
2. Replace `pick` with `drop` for commits you want to discard.
3. Save and exit.
4. `git push --force-with-lease` (safer force push, pointed out by @George)

Comment: this worked for me like a charm. I had bunch of commits which shouldnt have been in the PR. I just interactive rebased it, dropped those commits and pushed them back

Comment: You should sync with remote master before starting a pr anyway, no?

Comment: To push I had to do: `git push origin HEAD:myBranch --force`. But otherwise great and helpful.

Comment: @ScottyBlades I omitted that part  intentionally as it's out of scope. If you didn't set the tracking branch you either need to set it or, like you did, push explicitly.

Comment: This is also useful when you want to fix an open PR in GitHub, you just need to be able to do a forced push

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also it is better if you can cherry-pick the commit that you want to separate from the PR to another branch.

Comment: What do you mean by "Replace `pick` with `drop` for commits you want to discard."?

Comment: @jorijnsmit they mean after running `git rebase -i HEAD~<n>`, at the top of the file there will `<n>` lines of commits, with each line containing the text `pick <commit id>`. The commits default to `pick`, so for every commit you want to drop, change the text `pick` to `drop`

Comment: Silly question - is the "~" a part of the git rebase -i HEAD~n command?

Comment: Not at all. Yeah, it is a part of the command. @DougKimzey

Comment: This works like a treat. I created a branch that carried over a bunch of commits from the previous branch. So straightforward, unlike alot of git stuff!

Comment: For all those who don't know how to perform 4. step - Save and exit: type :wq! and press Enter key.

Comment: I find it easier to rebase onto the target branch, which is usually the one you branched from: f.x. `git rebase -i origin/main` this will show all the commits on your branch compared to the target branch.

Comment: Using `git push --force` could overwrite changes not seen on your local. To prevent removing others work by accident, use `git push --force-with-lease`.

Comment: @George Thanks, I learned this now, editing the answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you're removing a commit and don't want to keep its changes @ferit has a good solution.

If you want to add that commit to the current branch, but doesn't make sense to be part of the current pr, you can do the following instead:

1. use `git rebase -i HEAD~n`
2. Swap the commit you want to remove to the bottom (most recent) position
3. Save and exit
4. use `git reset HEAD^ --soft` to uncommit the changes and get them back in a staged state.
5. use `git push --force` to update the remote branch without your removed commit.

Now you'll have removed the commit from your remote, but will still have the changes locally.

Comment: Be very careful when using `git push --force`. It will completely (and irreversibly) override everything that's on the remote with the contents of your local computer.

Answer (score 5):

From your branch fire below commands

```
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -m "Detail of Your last commit that you want to see"
git push -f
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what helped me:

1. Create a new branch with the existing one. Let's call the existing one `branch_old` and new as `branch_new`.
2. Reset `branch_new` to a stable state, when you did not have any problem commit at all.
   For example, to put it at your local master's level do the following:

   git reset —hard master
   git push —force origin
3. `cherry-pick` the commits from `branch_old` into `branch_new`
4. `git push`

Answer (score 1):

So do the following ,

Lets say your branch name is my_branch and this has the extra commits.

1. `git checkout -b my_branch_with_extra_commits` (Keeping this branch saved under     a different name)
2. `gitk` (Opens git console)
3. Look for the commit you want to keep. Copy the SHA of that commit to a notepad.
4. `git checkout my_branch`
5. `gitk` (This will open the git console )
6. Right click on the commit you want to revert to (State before your changes) and click on "`reset branch to here`"
7. Do a `git pull --rebase origin branch_name_to _merge_to`
8. `git cherry-pick <SHA you copied in step 3. >`

Now look at the local branch commit history and make sure everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

If accidentally pushed unnecessary files and wants to remove them from PR then

```
 1. git reset <commit ID wherever you want to jump> 
 
 2. git restore <file name you want to remove> or git add <all the file
    names you want to add to commit>

 3. git commit -m “new commit message”

 4. git push -f //necessary to push forcefully (if anything is there to pull)
```